# Left join only on first row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I have the following sample query:

```
WITH a As
(
SELECT '2020-04-01' as date,'test123' as id,'abc' as foo,10 as purchases  Union all
SELECT '2020-04-01', 'test123', 'abc', 0   Union all
SELECT '2020-04-01', 'test123', 'abc', 0
),
b as
(
SELECT '2020-04-01' as date,'test123' as id,'abc' as foo,50 as budget
)
select
a.date,a.id,a.foo,a.purchases,budget
from a
LEFT JOIN b
ON
concat(a.date,a.id)=concat(b.date,b.id)
```

and I'd like the following output

```
Row date,id,foo,purchases,budget    
1   2020-04-01,test123,abc,10,50
2   2020-04-01,test123,abc,0,null
3   2020-04-01,test123,abc,0,null
```

I read many questions on the similar topic but I wasn't able to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select a.date, a.id, a.foo, a.purchases,
       (case when a.seqnum = 1 then b.budget end) as budget
from (seleect a.*, row_number() over (partition by date, id order by purchases desc) as seqnum
      from a 
     ) a
     b
     using (date, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the b inner query add this to the columns being selected:

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Purchases DESC) AS SequenceNumber

Then in your LEFT JOIN add "AND b.SequenceNumber = 1"

If you really are hard-coding everything and not selecting from an actual table, it would be:

```
WITH a As
(
SELECT '2020-04-01' as date,'test123' as id,'abc' as foo,10 as purchases  Union all
SELECT '2020-04-01', 'test123', 'abc', 0   Union all
SELECT '2020-04-01', 'test123', 'abc', 0
),
b as
(
SELECT '2020-04-01' as date,'test123' as id,'abc' as foo,50 as budget
)
select
a.date,a.id,a.foo,a.purchases,budget
from a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.date = b.date
    AND a.id = b.id
    AND a.purchases > 0
```

Otherwise, if you have a table in the inner "b" query. Then it would be something like this:

```
WITH a As
(
SELECT '2020-04-01' as date,'test123' as id,'abc' as foo,10 as purchases  Union all
SELECT '2020-04-01', 'test123', 'abc', 0   Union all
SELECT '2020-04-01', 'test123', 'abc', 0
),
b as
(
SELECT '2020-04-01' as date,'test123' as id,'abc' as foo,50 as budget,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY Id) SequenceNumber
)
select
a.date,a.id,a.foo,a.purchases,budget
from a
LEFT JOIN b
ON a.date = b.date
    AND a.id = b.id
    AND b.SequenceNumber = 1
```

Comment: What my b inner query in that case?

Comment: This doesn't work on my case because there isn't any duplicates on table b so all row will be one. the duplicates (based on the join I needs) are in table a